# How to Get a SharePoint Content Type by Name (Title) using CSOM with ExecuteQueryWithRetry

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, csom

We are using CSOM in a Windows Forms application that we inherited to bulk upload documents into SharePoint but we keep getting throttled (429 exceptions).

We decorated our http traffic as per the recommendations here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#csom-code-sample-executequerywithincrementalretry-extension-method

We also implemented `ExecuteQueryWithRetry` from the Client Context Extensions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontextextensions.executequeryretry?view=sharepoint-pnpcoreol-3.2.1810

Part of our code gets a content type using this recommendation and this is still getting 429 exceptions:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115499/get-a-content-type-by-name-title-using-csom

The question is, how do I replace the line

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

With

```
ctx.ExecuteQueryWithRetry(10,30000);
```

`ExecuteQueryWithRetry` doesn't exist in the context of `ContentTypeExtensions`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no `ExecuteQueryWithRetry` extension for CSOM but it should be easy to write own extension.

```
public static class ClientContextExtensions
{
    public static void ExecuteQueryWithRetry(this ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, int retryCount, int delayTimeMs)
    {
        var attemptCount = 0;
        if (retryCount <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(retryCount));
        }
        if (delayTimeMs <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(delayTimeMs));
        }
        while (attemptCount <= retryCount)
        {
            try
            {
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                return;
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                if (wex.Response is HttpWebResponse response 
                    && (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests 
                        || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable))
                {
                    // try read Retry-After header from the response
                    var retryAfterRaw = wex.Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.RetryAfter];
                    if (int.TryParse(retryAfterRaw, out var retryAfterSeconds))
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(retryAfterSeconds * 1000);
                    }
                    // otherwise use defined delay
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(delayTimeMs);
                    }
                    attemptCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Maximum retry attempts {0} exceeded.", retryCount));
    }
}
```

usage

```
ctx.ExecuteQueryWithRetry(10, 30000);
```

or inside the `ContentTypeExtensions.GetByName`

```
public static class ContentTypeExtensions
{
    public static ContentType GetByName(this ContentTypeCollection cts, string name)
    {
        var ctx = cts.Context;
        ctx.Load(cts);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryWithRetry(10, 30000);
        return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(cts, ct => ct.Name == name);
    }
}
```